# Where does a function return a variable inside another function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the values of variables by pressing a button. A command is attached to the button itself, which activates a function to collect variables and return them as a tuple.

```
from tkinter import Label, Tk, Button, Entry
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

def function_1():
    root = Tk()

    var_0_ent = Entry(root)
    var_1_cbbx = Combobox(root, values = list_1)
    var_2_cbbx = Combobox(root, values = list_2)

    def accept():
        var_0 = var_0_ent.get()
        var_1 = var_1_cbbx.get()
        var_2 = var_2_cbbx.get()
        all_var = (var_0, var_1, var_2)
        return all_var

    accept_btn = Button(root, ..., command= lambda: accept())
  

    var_0_ent.grid()
    var_1_cbbx.grid()
    var_2_cbbx.grid()
    accept_btn.grid() 

    root.mainloop()

function_1()
```

And here I don't understand where the `all_var` tuple `return`s to. Is this variable stored in the button (I understand that sounds silly-_-)? Or is it inside the parent function  and it now needs to be addressed somehow?

Comment: Nowhere. `tkinter` doesn't handle return value of Button's command in any way.

Comment: It doesn't, as far as I know. Whoever wrote that function didn't know how to use Tkinter.

Comment: It's returned in the lambda, but nothing is done with it. You basically have `command= lambda: _ = accept()`

Comment: BTW, `lambda: accept()` is equivalent to just `accept`.

Comment: @001 Why do I need  `_=` ?

Comment: @SasambaDio, you were told that that's what your command _is doing_, not that that's what it _should_ do. `_` is conventionally a placeholder; to a human reader who knows standard Python idioms, it means "we're throwing away this value".

Comment: Button command ignores the return value from the callback. You can however use a variable inside function_1 which you can modify inside accept, such as a list to which you can append